# ASP.NET MVC, definition of "members of a view model class"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am reading a book on ASP.NET MVC, and it refers to "**members** of a view model class"? Specifically what are "**members**"? An example would help greatly!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`class member`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645622%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) could be [`property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), [`field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx), [`method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), `constant`, `event`, ...

Here's an example of a view model with a property (which is a member):

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string FooBar { get; set; }
}
```

or with a property and a method:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string FooBar { get; set; }

    public string FormatTheFoo()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} bazinga", this.FooBar);
    }
}
```

As far as events are concerned, well, they are indeed members, but in terms of an ASP.NET MVC view model, they are probably not something commonly used.